# Serialization mode in LINQ to SQL

Tags: asp.net, linq, linq-to-sql

what is means of serailzation mode in LINQ to SQL?

what architecture does LINQ to SQL uses internally (connected or disconnected architecture)?

Answer (score 0):

LINQ has no serialization, and no architecture to call so.

LINQ = Lanquage Integrated Query is a ciompiler mechanism to translate your queries into expression trees that are forwarded to an IQueryable inteface for execution.

Whatever architecture you asume is done by implementations of LINQ (which you explictely do not ask about) like LINQ2SQL, EntityFramework and possibly a dozen or two others - and they can do whatever model they want.

Comment: but when u see properties of .dbml designer you can see there a property name as serilzation mode

Comment: Ah, so after the edit;)? LINQ supports whatever you make out of it - internally it is connected. It supported serialization and distributed non-connected architectures IF YOU WRITE THE PLUMBING CODE.

Comment: can you give any example for this

Comment: No, I dont use third grade data access layer, and with all respect for Microsoft finally trying, they are about 10 years behind O/R mappers technology wise. I rather use NHibernate or DataObjects.net.